# How do I make a beamer presentation with customized title page and footage

Tags: beamer

I'm going to make slides with a lot of math for my company, but I'm only given template for power point and keynote. I saved the title page from power point template and tried to set it as the background of the title page in my beamer presentation. But I have not been successful. Can some one here help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Here is a title page from power point. I want to use it as the background of the title page in my beamer presentation:
[image: title page]

Here is a regular page from power point. I want to use it as the background of all the subsequent slides in my beamer presentation.

[image: regular page]

Your help is highly appreciated!

by the way, I tried \titlegraphic, it couldn't put the image in the right position.

Here is the theme I used (two theme files below). 
beamerthemeAtlanta.sty

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header:
/cvsroot/latex-beamer/latex-beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeAtlanta.sty,v 1.1
2007/07/05 10:00:00 tantau Exp $

% Copyright 2007 by Rajbabu Velmurugan <rajbabu@ece.gatech.edu>
%
% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
% of the GNU Public License, version 2.

% This beamer 'Atlanta' theme is a modified version of the Warsaw theme.
% The main differences from the Warsaw theme include
%     - Uses a color theme relevant to Georgia Tech, Atlanta (gold, yellow, white, navy blue)
%       (beamercolorthemeyellowjacket.sty)
%     - Places the logo in the top-left corner of the slide
%     - Provides an option to modify the bullets used in item to be balls or triangles
%
\mode<presentation>

\newif\ifbeamer@itemtriangle%
\beamer@itemtrianglefalse%
\DeclareOptionBeamer{itemtriangle}[false]{\csname beamer@itemtriangle#1\endcsname}%

\newif\ifbeamer@tocitemnumbered%
\beamer@tocitemnumberedtrue%
\DeclareOptionBeamer{tocitemnumbered}[true]{\csname beamer@tocitemnumbered#1\endcsname}%

\dimen0=\beamer@leftmargin%
\dimen1=\beamer@rightmargin%
% left text margin
\DeclareOptionBeamer{lessleftmargin}{%
\multiply \dimen0 #1
\divide \dimen0 100
\setbeamersize{text margin left=\dimen0}}%

\ProcessOptionsBeamer

% right text margin
\DeclareOptionBeamer{lessrightmargin}{%
\multiply \dimen1 #1
\divide \dimen1 100
\setbeamersize{text margin right=\dimen1}}%

\ProcessOptionsBeamer


%% Styles from Warsaw
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usecolortheme{yellowjacket}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

%%
%% Inner theme modifications in Atlanta
%% Use ball or triangle as bullet for 'items'
\ifbeamer@itemtriangle
    \setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]
\else
    \setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\fi

%% Use numbered ball or unnumbered ball in TOC of outline
\ifbeamer@tocitemnumbered
    \setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[ball]
\else
    \setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[ball unnumbered]
\fi


%% Outer theme modifications in Atlanta
%% Right Sidebar - navigation symbol
\defbeamertemplate*{sidebar right}{atlanta}
{
  \vfill%
%  \llap{\insertlogo\hskip0.1cm}%
  \vskip2pt%
  \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
  \vskip2pt%
}
%% From beamerouterthemesplit.sty, to add logo at the top left corner of the frame
% Head
\ifbeamer@compress

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  %% Remove logo when we use 'compress' in beamer option
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}
%    \insertlogo
%    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\else

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,center]{section in head/foot}
    \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.35\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.35\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}

\fi


% toc: sphere - reduced size compared to the default size in 'beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty'
\normalsize
\pgfdeclareradialshading[bg,parent.bg]{tocsphere}{\pgfpoint{-0.4ex}{0.6ex}}%
{%
  color(0ex)=(bg!35!white);
  color(0.3ex)=(bg!75!white);
  color(0.6ex)=(bg!70!black!90!parent.bg);
  color(0.8ex)=(bg!50!black!90!parent.bg);
  color(1.0ex)=(parent.bg)}

 \mode <all>
```

**And beamercolorthemeyellowjacket.sty**

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header:
/cvsroot/latex-beamer/latex-beamer/themes/color/beamercolorthemeyellowjacket.sty,v
1.0 2007/07/05 10:00:00 tantau Exp $

% Copyright 2007 by Rajbabu Velmurugan <rajbabu@ece.gatech.edu>
%
% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
% of the GNU Public License, version 2.

% This beamer 'yellowjacket' color theme is used in 'Atlanta' theme. It is a modified version
% of the 'Whale' and 'Orchid' themes used by the 'Warsaw' theme.
%
% The main differences from the Warsaw theme include
%     - Uses a color theme relevant to Georgia Tech, Atlanta (gold, yellow, white, navy blue)
%       (beamercolorthemeyellowjacket.sty)
%     - Places the logo in the top-left corner of the slide
%     - Provides an option to modify the bullets used in item to be balls or triangles
%

\mode<presentation>

%% Authorized colors for Georgia Tech are gold (PMS 124), metallic gold (PMS 874), navy (PMS 539), and black.
%% RGB - #f0ad00 (PMS 124) 0.9, 0.67, 00
%% RGB - #cc9900 (PMS 874) 0.8, 0.6, 0
%% RGB - #00274d (PMS 539) 0.0, 0.15, 0.3
%% RGB - #050403 (black) 0.02, .015, 0.01
\definecolor{gtgold}{rgb}{0.9, 0.7, 0} % use structure theme to change
\definecolor{gtyellow}{rgb}{0.8, 0.6, 0}
\definecolor{gtnavy}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.3}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=gtgold}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=gtnavy, bg=white}%
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red}%
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=green!50!white}%

%% From beamercolorthemewhale.sty (outer color)
% the 'palette primary' and 'palette quaternary' control the color shading in the
% 'frametitle' field of the frame.
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=gtnavy,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=gtnavy,bg=structure.fg!75!black}%
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=gtnavy,bg=structure.fg!50!black}%
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{use=structure,fg=gtnavy, bg=white}%

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=gtnavy}%
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50}%
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=gtnavy}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

%% From beamercolorthemeorchid.sty (inner color)
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=gtnavy,bg=structure.fg}%
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted text,fg=gtnavy,bg=alerted text.fg!75!black}%
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=gtnavy,bg=example text.fg!75!black}%

\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}%
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!10!bg}%
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}%

%\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}%
%\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{bg=gtgold!90!white}%
%\setbeamercolor*{frametitle right}{bg=gtgold!90!white}%
```

\mode

**Update here** 
Thank you so much cfr for spending time on helping me!  I tried your code, but once I have sections in the slides, the navigation bar on the top shows up and block the blue bar on the background. Please see my code below. Also Can I change the color of "yellow" theme to "blue"? Because the theme color is not compatible with the background picture. Can you let me where I should change in the beamercolorthemeyellowjacket.sty file? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[font=9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Atlanta}
\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mytitle}[1][left]
  {
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
    \@tempdima=\textwidth%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{}
      \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
      \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
      \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
      \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
      {%
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
        \fi
      }%
      \vskip-1ex%
      \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[mytitle]


\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}




%\usepackage{Warsaw}
%\usepackage{beamercolorthemeyellowjacket}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifpdf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\def\Ze{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\Qe{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\Re{\mathbb{R}}
\def\Ne{\mathbb{N}}
\def\E{\mathbb{E}}
%\def\Pr{{\rm Pr}}
\def\newblock{}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\wg}{\wedge}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observation}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{asp}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newcommand{\rv}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\rr}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\zz}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\nn}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\rw}{W}


\newcommand{\rc}[1]{\textcolor{Black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bc}[1]{\textcolor{Black}{#1}}



\title[Presentation ] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Presentation Title}
\institute[my institute]{
  }
\author[my name ] % (optional, use only with lots of authors)
{my name}

\date[]

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{blue}}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background}}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction
\item A two-stage chance-constrained model
\item Case study
\item Solution approaches 
\item Conclusions 

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\


\end{center}

\end{frame}

\section{A two-stage chance-constrained model}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\


\end{center}

\end{frame}

\section{Case study}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\


\end{center}

\end{frame}

\section{Solution approaches }
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\


\end{center}

\end{frame}





\end{document}
```

Comment: You are most likely to get really helpful answers if you help people understand what you are trying to do as well as you can. By far the most effective way is to post a Minimum Working Example which shows what you've tried and to just explain which specific aspect of it you want to change. I get the change bit in this case but I've no idea what your current code looks like so it is hard to take it ans work on it. Ideally, you want people to be able to copy and paste something, compile it, reproduce the problem and then (hopefully) add a solution and post it back. Code > images!

Comment: PS Especially for me. I can't currently view any images inline on this site. But I can see code just fine!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I just got the title page problem solved. The trick is to

Comment: When posting code, please indent it by four spaces. The easiest way to do this is to highlight it and then press the {} button in the editor. You can see the effect in my edit to your post. This makes the code much easier to read and manage. Please also see my response to your comment on my answer. I'm just completely unclear what you are trying to do. It would help to see the code you have so far. It might also help to see a 'mock-up' of what you would like the result to look like.

Comment: cfr, thanks for spending time on my code. I was able to merge your code. But there is one problem. Please see the update of my update.

Comment: See my updated update below.

Answer (score 3):

So this may not be what you need since I don't know where you are starting:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{teitl}}
\frame[label=title]{\titlepage}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{tudalen}}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    This is a regular page.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page and regular page]

### Update

The only way I can currently figure to do this is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Atlanta}
\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mytitle}[1][left]
  {
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
    \@tempdima=\textwidth%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{}
      \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
      \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
      \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
      \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
      {%
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
        \fi
      }%
      \vskip-1ex%
      \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[mytitle]

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{teitl}}
% plain removes the navigation bar etc.
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{tudalen}}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    This is a regular page.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: hacked frametitle, no footline, plain titlepage]

### Update to Update

```
\documentclass[font=9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Atlanta}
\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{mytitle}[1][left]
  {
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
    \@tempdima=\textwidth%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{}
      \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
      \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
      \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
      \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
      {%
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
        \fi
      }%
      \vskip-1ex%
      \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[mytitle]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}% eliminate headline so background is revealed
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}% adjust as desired
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

%\usepackage{Warsaw}
%\usepackage{beamercolorthemeyellowjacket}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifpdf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\def\Ze{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\Qe{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\Re{\mathbb{R}}
\def\Ne{\mathbb{N}}
\def\E{\mathbb{E}}
%\def\Pr{{\rm Pr}}
\def\newblock{}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\wg}{\wedge}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observation}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{asp}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newcommand{\rv}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\rr}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\zz}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\nn}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\rw}{W}

\newcommand{\rc}[1]{\textcolor{Black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bc}[1]{\textcolor{Black}{#1}}

\title[Presentation ] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Presentation Title}
\institute[my institute]{
  }
\author[my name ] % (optional, use only with lots of authors)
{my name}

\date[]

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{blue}}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background}}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction
\item A two-stage chance-constrained model
\item Case study
\item Solution approaches
\item Conclusions

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\

\end{center}

\end{frame}

\section{A two-stage chance-constrained model}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\

\end{center}

\end{frame}

\section{Case study}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\

\end{center}

\end{frame}

\section{Solution approaches }
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A Frame Title}

\begin{center}
\bfseries{Thank you!}\\

\vspace{2cm}

\bfseries{Comments?}\\

\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi cfr, you rocks!  Yes, that's exactly what I want!  

But when I apply some theme, I found that the top of my background is covered by the theme picture (solid color). Especially, the title page was destroyed. I will post the code for the theme I'm using. If it does not take much time, would you mind modify the code and make my background not being blocked? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand. Of course, if you put a theme over the top of your background picture, it will block part of it. You cannot put two things in the same place and have them both show up! So do you want the background image to be made smaller so there is room for the theme elements? Or do you not really want those theme elements?

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't put a theme on top of it. But with a little modification, the theme will not block anything. The theme I'm using is attached to the original post. Two problems here:  1) one the title page, there shouldn't be navigation bar. 2) on a regular page, the blue bar on the background was blocked by the solid yellow color. 3) on a regular page, the blue bar at the bottom is partially blocked by the footage generated by the theme, I would like to remove this footage.  Thanks!

Comment: (1) and (3) are easy but you don't say what you want to happen with (2). That's setting your frame title etc.

Comment: For 2), can the solid yellow color be removed and reveal the blue bar on the background?  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you crf! Your code works! I really appreciated your time on helping me out! That's all I need for now.

Comment: @user43964 Please consider accepting my answer if this solved the problem. That way, other users can easily see that the answer resolved the issue.