# How do I create a Beamer presentation based on a Google Doc template?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I have a Google doc presentation template (two slides - title page and sample page) and I need to create a matching presentation using Beamer.

How do I do that?

I have a vague notion that this would require

- getting the graphics out of the template ([how?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77982/how-do-i-extract-the-graphics-from-a-google-presentation-template-for-use-with-b)) and
- telling beamer to use them as backgrounds ([how?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153462/46529))

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question we can answer here: it's not clear that there is any method for exporting Google doc templates, and such a question is off topic here anyway.  The question you linked to might get you started, but as you can tell, making new `beamer` themes isn't totally trivial, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @AlanMunn: thanks for your comment, I hoped that there are other people here who had similar problems and who thus could point me in the right direction.

Comment: @sds Idea only.  (Have not used or tried)  Get this script and convert the presentation to markdown http://lifehacker.com/this-script-converts-google-documents-to-markdown-for-e-511746113.  Now it is possible that the package in R `rmarkdown` can convert this to a Beamer Presentation and provide both the pdf and the `.tex` source code.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf

Comment: I think it's possible to export from Google Doc to power point, and from them you can apply [this VBA code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66314/1952) to convert to `beamer`. I used this second part sometimes and more or less worked for me. But I never used Google doc.